# Preventing Form Submission in Contact Form 7 When Location is Invalid

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, contact-form-7

I'm currently working on a project that uses Google's Places Autocomplete with Contact Form 7. I need to validate the location input by the user before the form is submitted.

The validation works correctly, and it correctly identifies when an invalid location is entered. like "qweqwe", However, the form is still being submitted, even when the location is invalid.

It seems like Contact Form 7 is treating the input as valid because it has a value, even if it's not a valid location.

I'm looking for a way to prevent the form submission until a valid location is entered.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const pickupInput = document.getElementById("places1");
  const dropoffInput = document.getElementById("places2");

  if (pickupInput && dropoffInput) {
    const center = { lat: 44.50000, lng: -89.50000 };

    const defaultBounds = {
      north: center.lat + 2.0,
      south: center.lat - 2.0,
      east: center.lng + 2.5,
      west: center.lng - 2.5,
    };

    const autocompleteOptions = {
      bounds: defaultBounds,
      strictBounds: true,
      types: ["address"],
      componentRestrictions: {
        country: "US",
      },
      fields: ["formatted_address"],
    };

    const pickupAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      pickupInput,
      autocompleteOptions
    );

    const dropoffAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      dropoffInput,
      autocompleteOptions
    );

    pickupAutocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
      const pickupPlace = pickupAutocomplete.getPlace();
      if (!pickupPlace.geometry) {
        return;
      }
    });
    document
      .getElementById("contact-form-1")
      .addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent form submit
        const pickupPlace = pickupAutocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!pickupPlace || !pickupPlace.geometry) {
          Swal.fire({
            icon: "error",
            title: "Error",
            text: "Invalid location.",
            confirmButtonText: "ok",
          });
          return false;
        }
      });

    dropoffAutocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
      const dropoffPlace = dropoffAutocomplete.getPlace();
    });
  }
});
```

**Update**
If anyone is interested in how I addressed this issue, here's my code. You can customize it based on your requirements.

**Complete js code**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const pickupInput = document.getElementById("places1");
  const dropoffInput = document.getElementById("places2");

  if (pickupInput && dropoffInput) {
    const center = { lat: 44.5, lng: -89.5 };

    const defaultBounds = {
      north: center.lat + 2.0,
      south: center.lat - 2.0,
      east: center.lng + 2.5,
      west: center.lng - 2.5,
    };

    const autocompleteOptions = {
      bounds: defaultBounds,
      strictBounds: true,
      types: ["address"],
      componentRestrictions: {
        country: "US",
      },
      fields: ["formatted_address", "geometry"],
    };

    const pickupAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      pickupInput,
      autocompleteOptions
    );

    const dropoffAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      dropoffInput,
      autocompleteOptions
    );

    pickupAutocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
      const pickupPlace = pickupAutocomplete.getPlace();
      console.log(pickupPlace);

      if (pickupPlace.geometry) {
        isPlaceSelected = true; // Set the flag to true if a place has been selected

        // Store the latitude and longitude in hidden fields
        document.getElementById("pickup-lat").value =
          pickupPlace.geometry.location.lat();
        document.getElementById("pickup-lng").value =
          pickupPlace.geometry.location.lng();
      } else {
        isPlaceSelected = false; // Reset the flag if no place has been selected
      }
    });
      document
      .getElementById("contact-form-1")
      .addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Always prevent form submission

        if (
          !document.getElementById("pickup-lat").value ||
          !document.getElementById("pickup-lng").value
        ) {
          pickupInput.style.outline = "2px solid red";
          Swal.fire({
            icon: "error",
            title: "Error",
            text: "Please select a valid pickup location.",
            confirmButtonText: "ok",
            didClose: () => {
              // Scroll to the pickup input field smoothly again after the modal is closed
              pickupInput.scrollIntoView({
                behavior: "smooth",
                block: "center",
              });
            },
          });
        } else {
          // Serialize the form data
          const formData = new FormData(e.target);
        }
      });
    dropoffAutocomplete.addListener("place_changed", function () {
      const dropoffPlace = dropoffAutocomplete.getPlace();
    });
  }
});
```

PHP code in your **functions.php** or **custom-function.php**

```
 add_filter('wpcf7_validate_hidden', 'validate_pickup_location', 10,2);

            function validate_pickup_location($result, $tag) {
            $tag = new WPCF7_Shortcode($tag);

            if ('pickup-lat' == $tag->name || 'pickup-lng' == $tag->name) {
                $lat = isset($_POST['pickup-lat']) ? trim($_POST['pickup-lat']) : '';
                $lng = isset($_POST['pickup-lng']) ? trim($_POST['pickup-lng']) : '';

                // Validate the pickup location
                if (empty($lat) || empty($lng)) {
                $result->invalidate($tag, 'Invalid pickup location.');
                }
            }

         return $result;
     }
```

Don't forget to add the the hidden fields in your contact form

```
[hidden pickup-lat id:pickup-lat]
[hidden pickup-lng id:pickup-lng]
```

More info: [here](https://primeoutsourcing.com/tutorials/content/contact-form-7-prevent-the-submission-when-google-autocomplete-address-is-invalid)

Comment: CF7 will submit regardless of field validation.  Validation takes place on the sever side, so it requires the form to be submitted to complete the validation, regardless of what you are doing in JavaScript.  You need to implement a custom script to programmatically disable the default submit action.  There are several similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=disable+contact+form+7+submit) already answered on this forum.

Comment: @Aurovrata i actually fixed it. by adding hidden field and validate on the server side.

Comment: great.  Another way to solve this is to disable the submit button itself until a valid location is filled in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Contact Form 7 form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954644/disable-contact-form-7-form-submit)

Comment: @Yrll i actually solved my problem.